# Современное значение слов высокоресурсный и низкоресурсный

Tags: грамотная-речь, значение-слов

У Ожегова:

> [РЕСУРС](http://ozhegov.info/slovar/?ex=Y&q=%D0%A0%D0%95%D0%A1%D0%A3%D0%A0%D0%A1)
> -а, м. 1. мн. Запасы, источники чего-н. Природные ресурсы. Экономические ресурсы. Трудовые ресурсы (часть населения страны, к-рая способна работать, участвовать в процессе производства). 2. Средство, к к-рому обращаются в необходимом случае (книжн.). Испробовать последний р. || прил. ресурсный, -ая, -ое (к 1 знач.; спец.).

Применительно к человеку, семье я понимаю, что ресурсы — это денежные накопления, недвижимость и т. п. — то, что позволяет сделать дорогую покупку или пережить трудный период. А слова *высокоресурсный* и *низкоресурсный* я привык слышать только по отношению к технике.

Но вот что нахожу в Нацкорпусе:

> Примечательно, что более часто негативные изменения способности россиян трудиться отмечают представители **низкоресурсных** групп: пожилые (53 процента), малообразованные (55 процентов), люди с низким доходом (54 процента)...  Впрочем, и в **высокоресурсных** группах доля таких респондентов весьма высока: 40 процентов молодежи, 37 процентов опрошенных с высшим образованием и 39 процентов с высоким доходом. [Евгения Гвоздева. Особенности национальной работы // «Отечественные записки», 2003]  [омонимия не снята]
>
> Крупный бизнес―это в основном люди, которые относились к наиболее **высокоресурсным** группам советского общества. [Анна Гараненко. Страшно богатые // Известия, 2007.08.09]
>
> Идентифицируют себя со средним классом чаще представители **высокоресурсных** групп―молодые люди со сравнительно высоким уровнем образования и доходов. [Будет ли в России бесклассовое общество? // Известия, 2005.11.10]

О каких ресурсах тут идет речь? Имеется в виду уровень доходов и образования?
Отражено ли такое понятое ресурсов в словарях?

Answer (score 2):

От существительного ***ресурс*** можно образовать прилагательное ***ресурсный*** и термины ***высокоресурсный, низкоресурсный,*** которые есть в орфографических словарях.

Значение их понятно: ***высокоресурсный*** – это имеющий высокий ресурс. Например: ***высокоресурсный двигатель.*** Ресурс двигателя показывает, как долго сможет проработать устройство, то есть речь идет о **временном ресурсе**.

Раньше эти термины  применялись преимущественно к природным запасам, к техническим устройствам, но теперь их значение расширилось. **У человека тоже есть определенные ресурсы:** время жизни (связанное с возрастом), денежный доход, уровень образования.

**Высокоресурсная группа** –  люди высокими показателями по всем этим статьям. Это социальная группа наиболее активных и трудоспособных граждан.

Такое разделение на группы, к примеру,  **удобно для социологов** при изучении общественного мнения.

Термины "высокоресурсный и низкоресурсный" в таком применении можно отнести **к спец. лексике,** которая может и не отражаться в общих толковых словарях.

Answer (score 1):

Термин **человеческий ресурс** известен довольно давно, а теперь вот появился и **человеческий капитал**.

Впервые мы видим его в работах Теодора Шульца (Theodore Schultz), экономиста, интересовавшегося трудным положением слаборазвитых стран. Шульц заявлял, что улучшение благосостояния бедных людей зависело не от земли, техники или их усилий, а скорее от знаний. Он назвал этот качественный аспект экономики «человеческим капиталом». Шульц, получивший Нобелевскую премию в 1979 году, предложил следующее определение:

> Все человеческие ресурсы и способности являются или врожденными, или
>   приобретенными. Каждый человек рождается с индивидуальным комплексом
>   генов, определяющим его врожденный человеческий потенциал.
>   Приобретенные человеком ценные качества, которые могут быть усилены
>   соответствующими вложениями, мы называем человеческим капиталом.

Говоря о бизнесе, можно описать человеческий капитал как комбинацию следующих факторов:

•   Качества, которые человек привносит в свою работу: ум, энергия, позитивность, надежность, преданность.

•   Способность человека учиться: одаренность, воображение, творческий характер личности, смекалка («как делать дела»).

•   Побуждения человека делиться информацией и знаниями: командный дух и ориентация на цели.
В управлении человеческие ресурсы — самый обременительный из всех активов. Почти безграничное разнообразие и непредсказуемость людей делают их невероятно сложными для оценивания, гораздо сложнее, чем любой электромеханический узел, поступающий с предписанными практическими спецификациями. Тем не менее люди — единственный элемент, обладающий способностью производить стоимость. Все остальные переменные — деньги и их «родственник» кредит, сырье, заводы, оборудование и энергия — могут предложить лишь инертные потенциалы. По своей природе они ничего не прибавляют и не могут добавить, пока человек, будь это рабочий самой низкой квалификации, искуснейший профессионал или руководитель высшего звена, не использует этот человеческий потенциал, заставив его работать.
http://www.vashakomanda.ru/article18.htm

Очень часто этим термином пользуется ФОМ - Фонд Общественного Мнения.

Группы «высокоресурсные работники» и «низкоресурсные пенсионеры» выделены по специальной методике ФОМ, основанной на сочетании методов оптимального шкалирования, факторного и кластерного анализа. Взрослое население России было разделено на пять групп и пятнадцать подгрупп. На три группы разделены трудоспособные россияне: «высокоресурсные работники», «среднересурсные работники», «низкоресурсные работники», и на две – неработающие пенсионеры: «среднересурсные пенсионеры» и «низкоресурсные пенсионеры».  http://bd.fom.ru/pdf/d11tpk12.pdf